# Java 8 - how to use predicate with operators?

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

Suppose I have the following code:

```
public int getNumOfPostInstancesByTitle(String postMainTitle) {
    int numOfIns = 0;
    List<WebElement> blogTitlesList = driver.findElements(blogTitleLocator);

    for (WebElement thisBlogTitle : blogTitlesList) {
        String currentTitle = thisBlogTitle.getText();
        if (currentTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(postMainTitle)) {
            numOfIns++;
        }
    }
    return numOfIns;
}
```

what is the proper way converting it with predicate lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate your `numOfInts` with a simple combination of `map`, `filter` and `count` :

```
return driver.findElements(blogTitleLocator)
             .stream()
             .map(WebElement::getText) // convert to a Stream of String
             .filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(postMainTitle)) // accept only Strings
                                                             //equal to postMainTitle
             .count(); // count the elements of the Stream that passed the filter
```

Comment: Note that you can use `.filter(postMainTitle::equalsIgnoreCase)`, though null-handling will be a different.